# MYSQL: Left JOIN from two SELECT to "fill gaps" in dates

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table "calendar"

```
+------------+
|  day_date  |
+------------+
| 2015-01-01 |
| 2015-01-02 |
| 2015-01-03 |
| .......... |
| 2015-07-14 |
| 2015-07-15 |
+------------+
```

With this query I can select the WEEK (that I need)

```
SELECT WEEK(day_date,1) AS NUM_WEEK,
YEAR(day_date) AS YEAR,
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(day_date),WEEK(day_date,1),' Monday'), '%X%V %W') AS date_start
FROM calendar
GROUP BY NUM_WEEK
```

And this is the result:

```
+----------+------+------------+
| NUM_WEEK | YEAR | date_start |
+----------+------+------------+
|       29 | 2015 | 2015-07-20 |
|       30 | 2015 | 2015-07-27 |
|       31 | 2015 | 2015-08-03 |
|       32 | 2015 | 2015-08-10 |
|       33 | 2015 | 2015-08-17 |
|       34 | 2015 | 2015-08-24 |
|       35 | 2015 | 2015-08-31 |
|       36 | 2015 | 2015-09-07 |
|       37 | 2015 | 2015-09-14 |
|       38 | 2015 | 2015-09-21 |
|       39 | 2015 | 2015-09-28 |
|       40 | 2015 | 2015-10-05 |
|       41 | 2015 | 2015-10-12 |
|       42 | 2015 | 2015-10-19 |
|       43 | 2015 | 2015-10-26 |
+----------+------+------------+
```

Now I have another table:

```
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| id | id_account | amount |  date_transaction   |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |        283 | 150    | 2015-06-21 15:50:47 |
|  2 |        283 | 47.74  | 2015-07-23 15:55:44 |
|  3 |        281 | 21.55  | 2015-08-24 12:27:11 |
|  4 |        283 | 11.22  | 2015-08-25 10:00:54 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
```

They are gaps in date.

With a similar query:

```
    SELECT WEEK(date_transaction,1) AS NUM_WEEK,
YEAR(date_transaction) AS YEAR,
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(date_transaction),WEEK(date_transaction,1),' Monday'), '%X%V %W')
AS date_start,
transaction.id_account,
SUM(amount) as total FROM transaction
INNER JOIN account ON account.id_account = transaction.id_account
WHERE amount > 0 AND transaction.id_account 
IN ( SELECT id_account FROM account WHERE id_customer = 12 )
GROUP BY id_account, WEEK(date_transaction,1)
```

I obtain this result (probably data are not accurate, referring to previous tables, just to explain).

```
+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+
| NUM_WEEK | YEAR | date_start | idAccount |  total   |
+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+
|       29 | 2015 | 2015-07-20 |       281 | 22377.00 |
|       30 | 2015 | 2015-07-27 |       281 | 11550.00 |
|       32 | 2015 | 2015-08-04 |       281 | 4500.00  |
|       30 | 2015 | 2015-07-27 |       283 | 1500     |
+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

What I would, RIGHT (or LEFT) JOINING the two tables?

1. The min (and max) WEEK, so I can... (see 2)
2. Fill the gaps with missing WEEKS with NULL VALUES.

E.g., in a more complicated resultset:

```
+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+
| NUM_WEEK | YEAR | date_start | idAccount |  total   |
+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+
|       29 | 2015 | 2015-07-20 |       281 | 22377.00 |
|       30 | 2015 | 2015-07-27 |       281 | 11550.00 |
|       31 | 2015 | 2015-07-02 |       281 | NULL     |
|       32 | 2015 | 2015-08-09 |       281 | 4500.00  |
|       29 | 2015 | 2015-08-09 |       283 | NULL     |
|       30 | 2015 | 2015-07-16 |       283 | 1500     |
|       31 | 2015 | 2015-07-16 |       283 | NULL     |
|       32 | 2015 | 2015-07-16 |       283 | NULL     |
+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Note, for example, that id=283 now has NULL at WEEK 29, 31 and 32, for example, like id=281 has NULL in WEEK 31.

I prepared also SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8fdc/3

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take a look on your question and i came up with this solution. Here is how your query could look like:

```
SELECT t1.NUM_WEEK, t1.`YEAR`, t1.date_start, t1.id_account, t2.total
FROM (SELECT c.NUM_WEEK, c.`YEAR`, c.date_start, a.id_account
      FROM (SELECT WEEK(day_date,1) AS NUM_WEEK,
                   YEAR(day_date) AS `YEAR`,
                   STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(day_date),WEEK(day_date,1),' Monday'), '%X%V %W') AS date_start,
                   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id_account) FROM account WHERE id_customer=12) AS accounts_id 
             FROM calendar
             GROUP BY NUM_WEEK) c
       INNER JOIN account a
       ON FIND_IN_SET(a.id_account, c.accounts_id)
       ORDER BY a.id_account, c.NUM_WEEK) t1
LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT WEEK(t.date_transaction,1) AS NUM_WEEK,
             YEAR(t.date_transaction) AS `YEAR`,
             STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(t.date_transaction),WEEK(t.date_transaction,1),' Monday'), '%X%V %W') AS date_start,
             t.id_account, SUM(t.amount) AS total 
      FROM `transaction` t
      INNER JOIN account a 
      ON a.id_account = t.id_account
      WHERE t.amount > 0 AND 
            t.id_account IN (SELECT id_account FROM account WHERE id_customer = 12)
      GROUP BY id_account, WEEK(date_transaction,1)) t2
 ON t1.NUM_WEEK = t2.NUM_WEEK AND t1.YEAR = t2.YEAR AND t1.id_account = t2.id_account;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8fdc/20) for that so you can check up result. Hope that is what are you looking for.

Little explanation:

First think i done is that I little modified your first query where you extract data from table calendar and add there one new column called accounts_id. That query now look's like this:

```
SELECT WEEK(day_date,1) AS NUM_WEEK,
       YEAR(day_date) AS `YEAR`,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(day_date),WEEK(day_date,1),' Monday'), '%X%V %W') AS date_start,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id_account) FROM account WHERE id_customer=12) AS accounts_id 
FROM calendar
GROUP BY NUM_WEEK
```

Please pay attention on this line in SELECT statement

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id_account) FROM account WHERE id_customer=12) AS accounts_id
```

**Note** that when you select for specific customer you need to change **customer ID** in this line too!!!

Here is [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8fdc/22) so you can check result that this query produce.

This is necessary because we need to connect each week with each account to get desired result.

Next step is to extend previous query so we could separate accounts_id column (look result of previous query) so we could get row for each value in that column. Extended query look like this:

```
SELECT c.NUM_WEEK, c.`YEAR`, c.date_start, a.id_account
FROM (SELECT WEEK(day_date,1) AS NUM_WEEK,
             YEAR(day_date) AS `YEAR`,
             STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(day_date),WEEK(day_date,1),' Monday'), '%X%V %W') AS date_start,
             (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id_account) FROM account WHERE id_customer=12) AS accounts_id 
       FROM calendar
       GROUP BY NUM_WEEK) c
INNER JOIN account a
ON FIND_IN_SET(a.id_account, c.accounts_id)
ORDER BY a.id_account, c.NUM_WEEK
```

and output you can see in this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8fdc/23)

After that all we need to do is to make left join between this query and query you already wrote in your question (last query).

There might be a better solution or even this one maybe can be improved a little, but I don't have much time now to deal with that and this is the first think that cross my mind...

GL!

P. S. pay attention when you use reserved word in MySQL like YEAR, TRANSACTION etc for column name (as column_name).. that can cause you a treble if have to use them in name of column or table use backquote (`) to mark them (as`year`)...

Comment: Everytime I think that YOU did write MySQL. Fantastic. Thank you very much